# How to prevent a decimal dot from being stored in Database from DataGridView c#?

Tags: c#, sql

I am new to c# and using windows forms. I set the `Datagridview` to accept only numbers and one decimal dot.

I store/Update the `Datagridview` cell values into sql table (money columns type). 
I do not want to store the decimal dot by itself into the sql table because the sql will not accept it and will throw an exception (because only double values are accepted)

so I wrote this code to prevent the decimal dot from being stored into the sql table by itself:

```
private void updateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {

   // connection string and the rest of sql stuff....

   MyCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Table1 SET ........");
   MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@value1", SqlDbType.Money);

 if (Convert.ToChar(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value) != '.')// if not dot then store it in database
            {
                MyCommand.Parameters["@value1"].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value);
            } 

}
```

However, this code did not works and still throw an exception (Input string was not in a correct format)  whenever I enter decimal dot by itself in `Row0, column1` and click update Button. 
Can anyone tell me why the if condition did not work? how can I make it work. Thank you

Comment: What kind of exception is being thrown?

Comment: @Nicholas Schuster. "Input string was not in a correct format" . any idea?

Comment: I suspect that Convert.ToDecimal is throwing that exception when you pass it a string that it cannot convert to a number. I suspect that dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value does not hold the value that you are thinking it does when a lone dot is entered into the cell.

Comment: Put a stop on the "if" line, debug down to there and paste the following into your Immediate Window of VS; ? Convert.ToChar(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value)

Comment: If the result of the above is actually '.' then I don't know, your if should catch it. If not, just adjust your if to look for the correct value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here does not seem to lie with the SQL Command but rather the conversion from `string` (in the `DataGridView`) to `double` fails (as @Kevin mentioned as well).

So why does it fail? We can only guess as we do not know the exact value that the cell holds at the moment. Obviously the check for the `'.'` character does not work. This would be problematic anyways if you used another language (for example german, where a `','` is used).

I would therefore suggest three things:

First:

Print out the exact value to the debug output (`System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value)`) to see the exact value your are getting and why. This simply has a learning purpose to see why your code failed and what other misbehaviour might happen.

Second:

Use `Decimal.TryParse` instead of your check for `'.'`:

```
decimal cellValue;
// Check if conversion possible
if (Decimal.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value, out cellValue)) 
{
    MyCommand.Parameters["@value1"].Value = cellValue;
} 
else
{
    /*Whatever you want to do in a fail case*/
}
```

This is more secure as you will always catch conversion problems.

Third:

Change the column type of your `DataGridView`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.valuetype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
This should avoid a lot of problems for you.